# PHPExcel saving HTML content to xls/x file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have this code:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'test');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I have 2 problems.
Any headers I tried to save the file with `.xlsx` extension didn't worked. they all gave me a corrupted file.

My second problem which is much more important - this code worked with `.xls` extension.

But it download a file with all of the `HTML` content of the page and when I opened it Excell is giving me an error that I missing the `css` file.

I'm using this code on the page `index.php` with `include()`, the css file is called in `index.php`.

any help would be appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this code in 4-5 projects and working perfectly, Check if helps

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Customers');
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Customers-"' . date('d-m-y-h-i-s', time()));
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
            exit;
```

Comment: I tried this code, gave me the same result for both of my problems

Comment: create a new file as test.php put this code and try. May be your file haeders already sent to server

Comment: Thank you it's working now. But now I get a lot of gibrish on the xls file. any suggestion?

Comment: I use the same code. my `xls` file should contain `test` on cell `A1` but I'm getting this file (picture): http://s28.postimg.org/sbwl03oq5/result.jpg

Comment: Make sure that __absolutely nothing__ is sent to the browser other than the datastream created when your save the PHPExcel object.... no whitespace outside of PHP tags, no BOM headers, nothing

Comment: Thanks! It was the BOM header which messed it up.